# too long video trace file volume?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, codec

I have produced an XML trace file of a 20-sec video and the volume of this trace file is 8.57 Gigabyte!! the videos is encoded using this command:

```
ffmpeg  -i  input_1080p60.mp4  -c:v  libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p  -b:v 8000K -bufsize 8000K -minrate 8000K -maxrate 8000K -x264opts keyint=120:min-keyint=120 -preset veryfast -profile:v high out_1080p.mp4
```

then I used the following command I changed the format in .264 because the input of JM software for producing an XML trace file is .264:

```
ffmpeg  -i  out_1080p.mp4  -c:v  libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p  -b:v 8000K -bufsize 8000K -minrate 8000K -maxrate 8000K -x264opts keyint=120:min-keyint=120 -preset veryfast -profile:v high out_1080p.264
```

after using JM using the following code:

```
ldecod.exe -i E:\software\out_1080p.264 -o E:\software\out.yuv -xmltrace out_1080p_xml.xml
```

it is really weird for me. because I have more than 1000 videos that I need to produce their trace files and I do not know what should I do with this size of the trace file. furthermore, I can not open a file with this volume and no software can open the file!!:((. could you please tell me what is the problem? and how can I solve it? do you know another way to produce this trace file?
THanks

Comment: No need to re-encode to get raw H.264 output. Just do `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.264`

Comment: Thank you. but my main question was about the size of XML file and how can I open it?